# Symfony permissions could not be fixed

Tags: svn, terminal, symfony1, config

thanks to everyone in advance. I am having trouble setting up a symfony site on my local. It is not allowing me to ./load-db. I went and ./symfony project:permissions on the root directory and I am getting this error.

```
 Permissions on the following file(s) could not be fixed:  

   - SF_ROOT_DIR/cache                                      
   - SF_ROOT_DIR/log
```

When I do  tail -f /opt/dev/logs/azandmeapp/error_log 
I get this error

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'sfDatabaseException' with message 'PDOException was
 thrown when trying to manipulate session data. Message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or 
 view not found: 1146 Table 'azandmeapp_site.http_session' doesn't exist' in 
 /opt/dev/kazaamprojects/azandmeapp/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/storage
 /sfPDOSessionStorage.class.php:169\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]:    
 sfPDOSessionStorage->sessionWrite('tdga8vm70sh5b0e...', '')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in  
 /opt/dev/kazaamprojects/azandmeapp/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/storage/
 sfPDOSessionStorage.class.php on line 169
```

i cant rm -rf the cache or the log.

Does anyone have an idea to help me. I surely do appreciate it.

Comment: Try to `chmod -R 777` your conflictive dirs. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: I tried chmod -R 777 first before I came to stack overflow. I am going to rm -rf the whole file and try from the start.  Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am silly, I the website had nothing in the db. I need to create a blank database and load with template data.

Therefore I needed to do

```
  ./symfony doctrine:build --db --and-load
```

Thank you everyone for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You have your problems with `./symfony project:permissions` probably because cache was initially created by your apache user so now you can't remove cache files.

What you need to do is make sure that directories

```
SF_ROOT_DIR/cache 
SF_ROOT_DIR/logs
```

are empty and then you need to run a command

```
./symfony project:permissions
```

which should run without any problems. Simplest solution to empty `cache` and `logs` is `rm * -rf`. If possible try to run this command as a root. If not you will have to remove cache and log files being an apache user. To accomplish this create a php script which you will run in a browser (so it will be run as a apache user) by hitting

```
http://localhost/yourProject/removeDirScript.php
```

Check [this](https://gist.github.com/tomaszmadeyski/337c8c7e66dd42475ec4) simple script which I used in similar case as yours. Only thing you need to do is change parameter of `rmdir` function at the bottom of script.